# Hardy's inequality with power weights

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, inequality

we have that

$$\hspace{20mm}\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dx \right)^{p} x^{\alpha} dx \leq \left( \frac{p}{p-\alpha-1} \right)^{p} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)^{p}x^{\alpha} dx     \hspace{20mm}(1)$$

for $p \geq 1$ and $\alpha<p-1$

$$\hspace{20mm}\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{x}\int_{x}^{\infty} f(t) dt \right)^{p} x^{\alpha} dx \leq \left( \frac{p}{\alpha+1-p} \right)^{p} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)^{p}x^{\alpha} dx     \hspace{20mm}(2)$$

for $p \geq 1$ and $\alpha>p-1$

Conditions for $p \geq 1$ and $\alpha<p-1$ are essential for (1). Indeed, if I consider the functions $f_{a}(x) = \mathcal{X}_{(a,a+1)}(x)$ with $a>0$ then for  $x \geq a+1$ we have $\mathcal{H}f_{a}(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} f_{a}(t)dt = \frac{1}{x}$. let's see the two cases we have,

Case $p\geq 1$ y $\alpha \geq p-1$.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \mathcal{H}f_{a}(x) \right]^{p}x^{\alpha} dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{x^{p}} x^{\alpha} dx  \geq \int_{a+1}^{\infty} x^{\alpha-p} dx = \left[ \frac{x^{\alpha-p+1}}{\alpha-p+1}\right]_{a+1}^{\infty} = \infty$$
Case $0<p<1$ y $\alpha<p-1$. We have

a) $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \mathcal{H}f_{a}(x) \right]^{p}x^{\alpha} dx  \geq \int_{a+1}^{\infty} x^{\alpha-p} dx = \left[ \frac{x^{\alpha-p+1}}{\alpha-p+1}\right]_{a+1}^{\infty} = \frac{(a+1)^{\alpha-p+1}}{p-\alpha-1}$$

b) $$\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{a}(x)^{p}x^{\alpha} dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(  \mathcal{X}_{(a,a+1)}(x)\right)^{p}x^{\alpha} dx = \int_{a}^{a+1} x^{\alpha}dx \leq a^{\alpha}$$

so

$$\frac{\int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \mathcal{H}f_{a}(x) \right]^{p}x^{\alpha} dx }{\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{a}(x)^{p}x^{\alpha} dx } \geq \frac{\frac{(a+1)^{\alpha-p+1}}{p-\alpha-1}}{a^{\alpha}} = \frac{1}{p-\alpha-1} \frac{(a+1)^{\alpha-p+1}}{a^{\alpha}} \rightarrow \infty$$

when $a \rightarrow \infty$

Therefore it would be proven. However, for dual inequality (2) I would not know how to do it. Conditions for $p \geq 1$ and $\alpha>p-1$ are essential for (2), if I take the same function I get that for $x<a$ we have

$$\frac{1}{x}\int_{x}^{\infty} f_{a}(t) dt = \frac{1}{x}  $$
let's see the thow cases we have,

Case $0<p<1$ and $\alpha \geq p-1$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{\infty} f_{a}(t)dx \right)^{p}x^{\alpha}dx \geq \int_{0}^{a} x^{\alpha-p}dx = \frac{a^{\alpha-p+1}}{\alpha-p+1} \rightarrow \infty $$

when $a \rightarrow \infty$

Case $p\geq$ and $\alpha \leq p-1$. I don't know how I could do this step

Thanks you so much.